# При коммите гит не видит изменений файлов

Tags: git, github, webstorm, git-commit

Я изменил часть файлов в своем проекте, и хочу закоммитить изменения. Однако эти файлы не отображаются как измененные. git status сказал что эти файлы модифицированы и "Changes not staged for commit". Я попытался добавить их через git add и git status показал "Changes to be committed", однако при попытке коммита, файлов до сих пор не видно. Коммит делаю через WebStorm с помощью функций IDE а не через терминал.

Comment: `git commit` сделали? Редактируете файл -> `git add` -> `git commit` -> `git push`.

Comment: Хм интересно, это помогло, все закоммитилось, видимо в IDE проблема какая-то